# My layout's markup moves off using ScrollView with ImageView and TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am a new user in Android dev. Actually I have one problem that I can't solve for much time.

I have a layout with Scroll View, there are ImageView and TextView in this ScrollView. You can see it in my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity ="center"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I take the data from JSON and using this layout for input it in.
There are images that have different forms.
So, please, help me with it. What I must to do with layout markup and what scaleType I must to use.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my English)

Comment: A picture of your issue, and what you want corrected, might help here.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you posted the code that takes the data from a json too.
For picking the right scaletype, [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) might help.

Comment: it is allright with Json and API, other images that have small and standarts forms open normall. The main problem is that some images look like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/qPvLEoR) and other look like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/qPvLEoR). On the second screenshot i scrolled it for maximum to bottom, but text is going to go under the screen.

Comment: These images are the same...? Still, please provide code - it makes it a lot easier for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hello) I have already solve  my problem. I need only to add this things

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

I just forgot what adjustViewBounds do)